# AWS account access via ADFS user access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I dont want to give access or shared key(key pair) . I want the user login via powershell to access AWS account using their AD account. This is possible with GUI web interface. I am just finding powershell access via username password .Is this possibe ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the AWSPowerShell module, it supports federated access with SAML and ADFS. This support was announced in a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/new-support-for-federated-users-in-the-aws-tools-for-windows-powershell/) on the AWS Developer Blog.